# How to model data

Tags: model, predictor, sensitivity-analysis

I am attempting to model a specific variable's sensitivity to a feature set. In concrete terms, I am trying to predict the duration (`PAUSE_KS`) of a letter (`KS`) within a word. I know that the letter's duration is sensitive to the probability of the word, the probability of the letter itself, and the location of the letter within the word. My data file has fields such as below.

```
KS  WORD    P_WORD_     P_KS_   INDEX   PAUSE_KS
lt  tilt    0.173       0.016   2       187
th  The     0.01923     0.4299  0       219
er  there   0.043       0.22    2       672
re  altered 0.02        0.016   4       281
lt  alt     0.03        0.010   1       141
```

How can I go about assessing the forces acting upon this variable? Ultimately, I would like to be able to create an algorithm/model for this.

Any help at all is appreciated. Please feel free to offer edits if the question is not worded clearly.

Comment: I think the title needs to be changed to something more informative.

Comment: What would you suggest? I'm not very conversant in stats